# Is it possible to turn this class into a generic one?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Is anyone able to "genericalize" the class listed at the bottom of this question? I would like the class not to be locked to a delegate of type "GetStateDelegate", but a general delegate. Is that possible?

I've tried a couple of things, but 1) C# does not like a class declaration of this kind:

```
public class StringToMethodMapper<T> where T: System.Delegate
```

This yields "Cannot use System.Delegate as type parameter constraint"

An hints to get me on the right track is appreciated. Also, if a solution exists, I want the consumer to be as little affected by the changes as possible. For instance, I'd rather not change the calling code for "Add(string, delegate)".

The code:

```
public delegate bool GetStateDelegate(object someObject);

public class StringToMethodMapper
{
    private Dictionary<string, GetStateDelegate> _methods;

    public StringToMethodMapper()
    {
        _methods = new Dictionary<string, GetStateDelegate>();
    }

    public void Add(string key, GetStateDelegate method)
    {
        _methods.Add(key, method);
    }

    internal virtual GetStateDelegate GetMethodFor(string key)
    {
        foreach (var storedKey in _methods.Keys)
        {
            if (key.ToUpper().StartsWith(storedKey.ToUpper()))
            {
                return _methods[storedKey];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of making it generic... well, it's sort of possible. I have a library called [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) which uses IL rewriting for generics with delegate constraints - and you could use the same IL rewriter in your code. It's pretty ugly though. Basically IL supports the constraint you want, but C# doesn't. Note that there's no possible constraint for "it should be a type deriving from `MulticastDelegate` but not including `MulticastDelegate` itself"... so someone *could* create a `StringToMethodMapper<MulticastDelegate>` but that's pretty unlickly.

If you're happy to stick to one *kind* of delegate signature (e.g. "always three parameters and a void return") then you can use the approach from George's answer. If it should be for *any* delegate type, then you're stuck with the IL rewriting approach or abandoning the constraint.

---

(Edited based on comments.)

In terms of the rest of the code, that's a very slow use of a dictionary. Currently you've got O(n) lookup. Just use normal `Dictionary` access via `TryGetValue`, but pass `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` (or something similar) into the constructor to get a case-insensitive match. That won't get a starts-with match, admittedly... but your current approach isn't deterministic anyway, as you can end up with "foo" and "fo" as keys in the dictionary, both of which will match - so you're relying on the order in which the iterator returns the keys. Not a great idea.

If you really need the `StartsWith` behaviour, you might want to investigate implementing a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) - or if you're happy with O(N) lookup, I would keep a `List<KeyValuePair<string, TDelegate>>` to make it clear that you're not really using it as a dictionary.

Comment: The point is to have a StartsWith comaprison so I cannot use TryGetValue. In my original code I have checks for duplicate matches which throws exceptions, but I left it out as it's irellevant for the question. I will look at your library though - looks interesting!

Comment: ...and I guess you answer my question with saying it's not possible to have _any_ kind of delegate.

Comment: @Nilzor: Well, only with the IL rewriting approach.

Comment: @Nilzor: I've added a bit more detail, and moved my comments about the overall design.

Answer (score 1):

Something like below, perhaps (typed without an IDE). Obviously client will need to add the generic parameters, but i think the call to add still work.

```
public class StringToMethodMapper<T, TResult>
{
    private Dictionary<string, Func<T, TResult>> _methods;

    public StringToMethodMapper()
    {
        _methods = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, TResult>>();
    }

    public void Add(string key, Func<T, TResult> method)
    {
        _methods.Add(key, method);
    }

    internal virtual Func<T, TResult> GetMethodFor(string key)
    {
        foreach (var storedKey in _methods.Keys)
        {
            if (key.ToUpper().StartsWith(storedKey.ToUpper()))
            {
                return _methods[storedKey];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is what comes closest to what I want to acheieve given what's possible in C#. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to swap your delegate for an interface

```
public interface IGetState
{
   bool GetState(object someObject);
}
```

then you can use this interface as your constraint

```
public class StringToMethodMapper<T> where T: IGetState
{
   ...
}
```

You can then implement the interface to make something specific, for example:

```
public class FileSystemState : IGetState
{
   public bool GetState(object someObject)
   {
      // get state from the FS
   }
}
```

and then

```
var fileSystemMapper = new StringToMethodMapper<FileSystemState>();
```

Comment: This would work, but it would force me to change the calling code.